# binding data not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a new with AngularJS, and I am trying to bind data to the form controller, but it is not working.

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp"  data-ng-controller="simpleContr">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="user in users">
            {{ user.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS

```
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('simpleContr', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        { name:'Ashraf', city:'Cairo'},
        { name:'Ali', city:'Assuit'},
        { name:'Mohammed', city:'Qena'}
    ];
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the console

Comment: If you are using JSFiddle to test this, make sure that you select `No wrap - in <head>` ([Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406633/angularjs-uncaught-error-injectormodulerr-failed-to-instantiate-module))

Comment: You code works: http://jsfiddle.net/jwqnm05f/ you probably forgot to add a reference to the AngularJs library

Comment: @Josep Even if @Ashraf did use JSFiddle, the default is `onLoad`, which will not work.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl the OP hasn't mention anything about jsFiddle. I already knew that, if you check my jsFiddle example I'm already doing that.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl sure, and if the OP is using plunker then they have to make sure to include the library and if they are using jsbin same thing and if... You could make a long list here, the point is that the code works and that IMO there is no need for an answer because there is nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

The following works below, because the javascript is inserted into the head of the output document.

#### How to structure the `<head>`

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Your controller code...
    </script>
</head>
```

#### Working snippet

```js
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('simpleContr', function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{
        name: 'Ashraf',
        city: 'Cairo'
    }, {
        name: 'Ali',
        city: 'Assuit'
    }, {
        name: 'Mohammed',
        city: 'Qena'
    }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" data-ng-controller="simpleContr">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: An answer for this? really?

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl thanks the problem was that the js code was in the body area